# Know when polyline path variable change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a editable polyline and I need to know when this polyline change their path variable. It is posible to add a new event ("path_change" or some like this) into my polyline?

Thanks

Regards
cadetill

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was just facing this problem.  I solved it by adding event listeners to the polyline path, which is implemented as an mvc array. I used the mvc array events documented here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray

Once you have your polyline set up:

```
var path = poly.getPath();
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'insert_at', function(){
alert("path insert_at event");
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'remove_at', function(){
alert("path remove_at event");
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(){
alert("path set_at event");
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The next comment below is what actually happens if this code is used. Works for polygons tho

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to add an event to the Polyline object. See the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)  I'm also not sure what events are triggered during an edit, but I assume 'click', 'dblclick', etc are triggered. You'll need to run tests to see what events signal the end of the edit. Assuming you've saved the array returned by Polyline.getPath() before the edit, you'll need to check that against the new getPath() results to determine if they've changed.  Since path is an array of LatLng objects you could use LatLng.equals(*LatLng*), along with basic array.length checks, etc. Could be that LatLngArray.join() could be used to compare the two arrays.

Comment: Hi Eric. 

Thanks for your answer. I have testing all events from polyline and no event is triggered when a path change. In fact, no event is triggered when mouse interact with square of points to move actual lat/lng or create a new path.

Is for this that I like to create a new event for path change.

Thanks